# single sign on libraries

Tags: asp.net, security, single-sign-on

If I need to implement a single sign on in the new web site(asp.net), which exisitng 3rd party library you will recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe stackoverflow themselves use http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Is oauth what you are thinking of?